# How to change color of listview items

Tags: wpf, listview

i have a short question about ListView. I have a listview control in my wpf Calendar application with 3 items in it showing the events and their priority for the day (High Priority, Normal Priority and Low Priority 2). I would like to change the color of those events according to their priority (0,1,2) and show them in my listview.
I hope my question is not very stupid.

Comment: Try add style in your .xaml and setter property  , you can refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126393/how-i-change-listview-item-background-color-according-to-listview-item-harfnotu

Answer (score -1):

```
Thanks for the help. This is my code that works :)  

 <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="lvDetalji" Visibility="Hidden" Background="SeaGreen" BorderBrush="SeaGreen" Foreground="White" MouseDoubleClick="lvDetalji_MouseDoubleClick" >
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DogPrioritet}" Value="0"> <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />  </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DogPrioritet}" Value="1"> <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro" /> </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DogPrioritet}" Value="2"> <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" /> </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: The Style should be assigned to the ListView's ItemContainerStyle.